# warning : static class members may be accessed by the scoping operator

Tags: c++, file-io

I am observing compiler warning which says "Info -- static class members may be accessed by the scoping operator". Warning is observed while using inFile.seekg(0, inFile.end) and inFile.seekg(0, inFile.beg)

What does warning exactly mean - I googled but couldnt find much.

```
 /*Gets the size of file in bytes*/
    inFile.seekg(0, inFile.end);
    lengthOfFile = (int)inFile.tellg();

    /*Resets the pointer to beginning of File*/
    inFile.seekg(0, inFile.beg);
```

Comment: `inFile.beg` this presumably triggers the warning, not `tellg`

Comment: What compiler and version are you using?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki -you are correct - I have edited the question to reflect it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may access a `static` member variable using the member access syntax from an object or using the class scope operator.

Example:

```
struct Foo
{
   static int bar;
};

int Foo::bar = 0;

int main()
{
   Foo f;
   f.bar = 10;     // Access Foo::bar using the member access syntax from f
   Foo::bar = 20;  // Access Foo::bar using the class scope operator.
}
```

Both are valid ways to access `Foo::bar`. The compiler is, apparently, trying to be helpful. It's letting you know that you can access the object using the class scope operator.

In your case, you can use either of the following two forms:

```
inFile.seekg(0, inFile.beg);
inFile.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
```

Comment: Thank u for such nice and simple explanation. Any reason, since both are acceptable format of accessing data element, why would compiler throw the error. Any rules when to use one format over the other ? Intuitively I feel more comfortable with inFile.seekg(0, inFile.beg); , any situations when to use other format over these ?

Comment: Both are legal. I don't know why your compiler thinks using `inFile.beg` is an error. From your post, it seems like an "info" message.

Comment: sounds good - once again thanks for nice and detailed explaination

Answer (score 4):

I think the warning is about `inFile.beg` and `inFile.end`, that are static members of `std::ios_base`. So, you may want to refer to them as `std::ios_base::beg` and `std::ios_base::end`.

Both ways of accessing static members are legal, but I prefer the *scoping operator* version because it doesn't leave room to ambiguities.

Comment: yes, you are correct - that was error from my end - Let me try it out with your suggestion